# Can rate constant for forward reaction be equal to rate constant for backward reaction?

Tags: equilibrium

For a particular reaction, can we have
$K_c = 1$?

My confusion arised when I was studying the effect of temperature on $K_c$ . I see that the temperature must affect forward and backward rate constants, differently for a reaction so that it changes $K_c$ (which is ratio of the two rate constants). So I thought for a reaction with $K_c$ equal to one, both the rates must be equal, so both will get equally affected by temperature, and thus no change in $K_c$ , or does it have something to do with the Arrhenius equation?

I know that there is a lot of lacking in my intuition as I have just began studying Le Chatelier's principle and all the stuff. So a detailed explanation would be much welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Same Activation Energy for Forward and Backward Reactions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118579/same-activation-energy-for-forward-and-backward-reactions)

Comment: A part of it perhaps,so that I conclude that Kc will not be affected by temperature then(if Kc =1).

Comment: No. If you read the linked answer, you'll see that the requirement is that the enthalpy change is 0. K=1 only means that $\Delta G=0$. That only requires that $\Delta H = T\Delta S$. In the case where $\Delta H = \Delta S = 0$, there will be no temperature effect, but otherwise there will be a temperature effect. (And K=1 will only occur at one temp).

Answer (score -1):

When forward and backward reaction have the same rate, $K_c$ is equal to $1$ in the case of a reaction where the total number of reactants is equal to the total number of products in the chemical equation describing the change. If the total of these stoichiometric coefficients is not the same before and after the horizontal arrow, $K_c$ may be equal to $1$, but must have a dimension, like mol/L or L/mol, or any combination of these units.

As the forward and backward rections have different activation energies, their rates change differently with increasing the temperature. So the equilibrium constant $K_c$ can be equal $1$ at only one temperature.

Comment: But this is not true for many reactions, is it? For instance what about reaction    2ICl <-->Cl2+ I2     Kc is 0.001 even though the reaction has same stoichiometric coefficients

Comment: The important factor is not the coefficients, but the relative contribution of enthalpy and entropy. Also K is *always* dimensionless because it is technically calculated from activities not concentrations.